# How to insert multiple rows in pivot table using Eloquent?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, pivot-table

I have a pivot table called `user_machine_pivot` that connects two tables: `user` & `machines`, and when creating a new user i'm selecting the machines he can operate on from a dropdown list. What i'm trying to achieve is, when i make a `axios.post` request i want to insert multiple rows in the pivot table with the `user_id` & `machine_id`. Here's my User model code:

```
public function machine()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Machine::class, 'user_machine_pivot')->withTimestamps();
}
```

My `axios.post` request contents from Telescope:
{

```
full_name: "RandomName",
username: "RandomName",
password: "********",
machines: [
3,
2
]
}
```

My UserController:

```
$user = User::create($validatedUserData);
$user->machine()->attach($user->id, ['machine_id' => $machines]);
```

First, i'm validating the UserData & creating a User, and then i'm trying to attach the user to the machines in the pivot table.
Any help & pointers are appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$user->machine()->attach($user->id, ['machine_id' => $machines]);
```

That ain't right. You already have `$user`, and you want to attach a specific `machine`, so you need to pass that id to `machines()->attach()`:

```
$user = User::create($validatedUserData);
$machine = ...; 
// Not sure how you're getting `$machines`, and it should be singular `$machine`

$user->machines()->attach($machine->id, [...]);
// Replace `[...]` with any additional columns.
```

Note, if you want to attach multiple, you use `attach()` or `sync()`:

```
$user->machines()->attach($machines);
$user->machines()->sync($machines);
```

`attach()` is best used if you have existing records attached, as `sync()` will `detach()` then `attach()` the `ids` you're passing. Also, if you need additional columns, adjust your `$machines` to be an associative array:

```
$machines = [
  1,
  2 => ["additional" => "column"],
  3
]; // Etc. etc.
```

Comment: Thank you for the thorough answer, sir!

Comment: No problem! Happy to help!